# How to sum up step1 and step2 to reach the given distance, count the various sums of these steps and return it as an integer?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int jump(int distance, int range1, int range2){

    int res = 0, counter = 0;
    
    range1 + range1 + range1 + range1
    counter = range1 + jump(distance, range1, range2) == distance ? 
    
    if ( range1 + jump(distance, range1, range2) == distance ){
        counter++;
    } else if (  )
    
    range1 + range1 + range2
    
    range2 + range1 + range1
    
    range2 + range2 

    return counter;
}
```

**Example & instructions for this function:**
*Method call:* `jump(4, 1, 2);`
*Output:* `5`
*What the function should do in the background:*
`1 + 1 + 1 + 1`
`1 + 1 + 2`
`1 + 2 + 1`
`2 + 1 + 1`
`2 + 2`
So it eventually was able to sum up the steps1 and steps2 5 times differently and should `return 5` then.

Comment: This piece of pseudo code won't compile. And I definitely don't understand what it is intended to do (syntax error, sorry). recursively calling the function itself with exactly the same arguments as it has been called with is very likely to end in a stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do recursive calls ex `jump(3, 1, 2)`

```java
                            jump(3, 1, 2)
                          /              \
                 jump(2, 1, 2)           jump(1, 1, 2)
               /          \                 /
      jump(1, 1, 2)      jump(0, 1, 2)  jump(0, 1, 2)
       / 
jump(0, 1, 2)
```

Note: we are able to reach `jump(0, 1, 2)` exactly 3 times, therefore, the answer is 3.

On each function call, we need to deal with any of one of these 3 cases:

case 1: When the distance is less than 0, which means exact steps were not chosen and so we don't count this path and return 0

case 2: When the distance is exactly 0, which means exact steps were chosen and we return 1

case 3: When the distance is greater than or equal to step1 or step2 so we make a recursive call, which is the sum of choosing step1 and step2

```java
class Solution {

    public static int jump(int distance, int a, int b) {
        if(distance < 0) return 0; // case 1
        if(distance == 0) return 1; // case 2
        return jump(distance - a, a, b) + jump(distance - b, a, b); // case 3
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(jump(3, 1, 2));
    }
}
```

`output: 2`

Comment: Sadly, when trying ur code with jump(5,2,3) it returns 3, but it should return 2 as there are only 2 various possibilities to jump the distance 5:
2+3 (1)
3+2 (2)

Comment: I previously thought step 1 and step 2 are fixed, I have updated the answer. There must be an iterative solution also.

Comment: Ok thanks for this cool solution, but how can I put the ways variable as local variable inside the function and return the value for using it in main?

Comment: And would you mind to explain the recursive method call briefly, cause I have never seen such method call with a math operation inside - is it something special like the lambda expressions etc?

Comment: I have updated the answer now we can only work with local variables.

Comment: No, it's not a lambda expression. We can pass a math operation because `distance - a` or `distance - b` results in an `int` which is basically the data type of the first argument. We are free to pass anything as an argument as long as the result satisfies the datatype used when defining the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219741/discussion-between-torbenit-and-lovesh-dongre).